# How Typescript infer type of an array with generic type

Tags: typescript

**Code**

```js
type A = {
  name: string
}

type B = {
  id: number
}

function foo<T extends A | B>(target: T[]): T[] {
  const res = [];
  // const res: T[] = []; // Adding type annotation to res can resolve the error but why?
  for (const e of target) {
    res.push(e);
  }
  return res // TS think res is a type of (A|B)[] --> error!
}

function aoo<T extends A>(target: T[]): T[] {
  const res = [];
  for (const e of target) {
    res.push(e);
  }
  return res // TS think res is a type of T[] --> no error!
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUB2BDAthAXFAM7ABOAlhgOYoC+KKokUAQgsmlOQCaEYCuOAEYRSdBgDN+GAMbByAewxQJChQB4AKlAgAPYBAzcisKAB9WAPgAUwLKSoRghTQG0AugEoXHjuhlKJFCkECaIHgDcnAD00VABGEEhRD7u7JFQsbDc3JRUUEzQWBgYCnbySgUKwaHxxTVECgA2AG7QwAAW0KKkCqRQQvzAUADuHSAA-Jyq-dYJQdAKEgX2jsCefugNAHRg-EQd1hCeUej06CHA-KTKyZlxmgDKBR2UANYNXCZYBeCLy9YYGYWJ5fABaMGWHSkXqkACE4hQUlkFWUWDUWh0+kMxlgNjsDicqW8UDcaVQ-kCwzu4XcpxUfSgcypOigSxWhPWmwuoV2+0Ox3p5xqVxunyyTxe70+5G+v2Y7LJUAhUNK0NhCPoDCAA)

Basically, I have two types A and B, and two generic functions `foo` and `aoo`.

The first function `foo` has a generic type `T` which is constrained by a union: `A | B`, while the latter one is only constrained by `A`.

**Error**

The error appears in `foo`, and the reason is that TS thinks the result is a type of `(A|B)[]` which is incompatible with `T[]`. However, the return type of `aoo` is inferred as `T[]` as I expected. This is weird to me, I don't understand why TSC doesn't infer the return type of foo as `T[`], and what's the difference between these two cases?

Comment: I can't find a canonical answer here.  This has to do with *auto-typed* variables, also known as *implicit any* variables.  You've got an auto-typed array, but you can reproduce for non-arrays like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8oK0W). These were implemented in [ms/TS#11263](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263) and [ms/TS#11432](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11432). It seems that when the type evolves to a union-constrained generic, it is widened to the constraint, but when the type evolves to a non-union constrained generic, it is not widened.

Comment: I haven't found an issue filed about this in GitHub yet but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Looks like this started between TS4.2 and TS4.3

Comment: Absent in 4.3.0-dev.20210316, present in 4.3.0-dev.20210323

Comment: Found it, it's https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43183.  This was introduced for control flow analysis and has this side effect.  I can write up why this is happening I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the material @jcalz! But I still found `constrained position` a bit confusing. Is that mean the block inside a `for...of` loop is a constrained position in typescript?

Comment: It says "constraint position" (not "constrained") and it looks like it's a term that means it's an a position where the value can be widened to the generic constraint. You can look at the `isConstraintPosition()` function in the TS compiler `checker.ts` file, but it might not be too informative.  It's the fact that it is being passed to `push()` that puts it in a "constraint position", apparently.  Shall I write up an answer or am I still missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This is a side effect of the support added in Typescript 4.3 to [contextually narrow values of generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics), as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#43183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43183).  There was a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) where [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) would not work to narrow values of generic types [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), the same way it would work with values of specific types.

For example, the following always worked, where `x` is of the specific union type `string | number`:

```
function checkSpecific(x: string | number) {
  if (typeof x !== "string") {
    console.log(x.toFixed(2)); // okay
  }
}
```

Here the fact that `typeof x !== "string"` allows the compiler to narrow `x` to `number` and see that it has a `toFixed()` method.  But the following did not work before TypeScript 4.3, where `x` is of the type `T extends string | number`:

```
function checkGeneric<T extends string | number>(x: T) {
  if (typeof x !== "string") {
    console.log(x.toFixed(2)); // error (before TS4.3)! 
    // ---------> ~~~~~~~
    //  Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'T'.
  }
}
```

The compiler stubbornly refused to see that `typeof x !== "string"` had any implications on the type of `x`.  One thing the compiler *can't* do is assume that the type parameter `T` itself should be narrowed.  After all, maybe `T` really is the full union `string | number` (e.g., `checkGeneric(Math.random()<0.5 ? "abc" : 123)`) and so it wouldn't be right to narrow `T`.  But people who wrote the above code don't care about narrowing `T`, they wanted `x` to be narrowed from `T` to `number`.

And so with TypeScript 4.3, in certain situations when given values of generic types where the generic type parameter is constrained to a union, these values will first be widened all the way to the constraint and then narrowing can happen:

```
function checkGeneric<T extends string | number>(x: T) {
  if (typeof x !== "string") {    
    console.log(x.toFixed(2)); // okay (TS4.3 and above)
  }
}
```

The compiler has decided to take `x` and see its type not as the generic type `T`, but as the specific type `string | number` to which `T` is constrained.  And once it does this, then `typeof x !== "string"` can narrow `x` to `number` as desired.

---

Unfortunately, in your code, the same analysis leads to surprising behavior.  Prior to TypeScript 4.3, there would be no error:

```
function foo<T extends A | B>(target: T[]): T[] {
  const res = []; // <-- auto typed
  for (const e of target) {
    res.push(e); // <-- res is inferred as T[] before TS4.3
  }
  return res // okay
}
```

The variable `res` is considered to be an "auto-typed" or "implicit `any`" variable because the compiler cannot use its initializer to infer the type; it needs to wait to see what you do with it and then *evolve* the type based on that.  For arrays like `res` this was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#11432](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11432).

Before TypeScript 4.3, when you called `res.push(e)`, the compiler would see that `e` is of type `T`, and thus `res` is now evolved to be of type `T[]`, and then `return res` is fine.

But starting with TypeScript 4.3, this has changed:

```
function foo<T extends A | B>(target: T[]): T[] {
  const res = []; // <-- still auto typed
  for (const e of target) {
    res.push(e); // <-- res is inferred as (A | B)[] starting with TS4.3
  }
  return res // error!
}
```

The `res` variable is still auto-typed and evolves when you call `res.push(e)`.  But because the value `e` is of a generic type constrained to a union, the compiler uses its new behavior to first widen `e` from `T` all the way to the constraint `A | B`.  And that means that `res`'s type is `(A | B)[]` and you get an error.  Since you never tried to narrow `e` from `A | B` to either `A` or `B` in this code, the added support for control flow analysis is completely useless for your purposes.

Oh well.

---

Note that neither the old nor the new behavior is *incorrect*; a value of type `T` where `T extends XXX` can be widened to `XXX` safely.  It's just that there are some situations in which `T` will be more or less useful than `XXX`. The heuristics added in TypeScript 4.3 improved things for a lot of situations, but unfortunately made things worse in others.  I'd be interested in seeing what would happen if someone filed an issue about this, but I wouldn't go so far as to call it a bug.

[Playground link to code pre-ms/TS#43183](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-dev.20210316#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawMoAcMzAwQAUAHgFyIDOUATjGAOaIA+iYIAtgEZp0BKRAG8AsAChEiQohJQAnvjjBEZRAEIAvJsQAiWg2a6hYyVOQJqcADZoAdNbhNydqHABiMMmgAmJAEwCAgDciAD0YYhwmACG8hJSAL4SyeISoJCwCMjoWADiaGD8xAA8ACqIaGRQhT7UNPSMLOycvPwAfORUZSYJ0ipyimjKqhraegZNxiJ9UhCWNvaOzmSuHl6+AUGhEZV0dHB06ogACgf4dAqIAORunt4+14g+cGj1YHBQlWQwtFFICnwNzK1zsfVSqQkUPEgLQiAAgogdKYpGAYlw0FRJswUtDYYgAEJImZmGA+KitPh0XFpcQZaDwJDAOBwcrfGpgOoItiEzpQGJ0JhoKDdADaAF0BGLxSS5pYvnQ3sSJcE+rt5mA-orqNLleKdpF4T4fE1EPiYmAPvysgC4IhtcgLfa3jYAG5wqDoPYHOiIHggL4AdxQ8gA-H1mb6SBq-nCRvzBcLemYpNq7LgQNQUCQ0CFwX1FVAQHQkA7dtE4jT0uAGdkYiy2VUOVz4XyBUKRYgyhKpV2JbKLJqFUqdCqI4dZDGvnGVAmO8nzM7qOnM9nc6qzKlU8Li6WlbsytgzShGJgl9J6jEzUMoipuzKALQP9ocO38H3qFJAA)

[Playground link to code post-ms/TS#43183](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-dev.20210323#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-NIxDdDDUChs3zdlwIGoKBIaBCkr6MopSGb+z7zvEpwubobVbgXoqPue6uDofDgOjsY-8e1s7bRajLMpCnWQ-3nFRF2XVdzHXTdt13fdjkPMlj3-fYymwAVGEwf8hSrPEhiiFQymjRAAFoyPaDgWXPdQUiAA)

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz! This cleared my confusion, really appreciate the detailed answer and related materials!